# JPA query to non entity class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a generic way to return data in non entity objects. For example, I want to have a reduced version of an entity because I need to show in the front end a list of them.

The problem is that I can't really go with the annotation `@Query([query], native)...)` because I have optional filters, so I build the query dynamically.

So I am trying to use the

```
EntityManager.createNativeQuery([query]).getResultList()
```

and I get a list of Object. What I want is a way for it to return a `List<T>`.

What I've tried so far:

```
return (List<T>)(T) query.getResultList();
```

This appears to do absolutely nothing.

TLDR; I need a way to dynamically create queries (because I've got optional filters) and return a list of `T`, `EntityManager.createNativeQuery([query]).getResultList()`, so far gives me a list of Object that can't seem to be cast to `T` .

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JPQL instead of a native query you could use the following approach:

Let's imagine you have an entity Person. Then you can define a projection for the person just containing the names like this:

```
package de.models;

public record PersonNames(String vorname, String nachname) {
}
```

You can use JPQL`s constructor expression creating this dynamically with createQuery:

```
List<PersonNames> p = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT new de.models.PersonNames(vorname, nachname) FROM Person p",
                PersonNames.class
        ).getResultList();
```

Now this is not very generic and not really for a Class T, but if you really need a generic approach you kind of have to create it yourself. A very simple implementation could be

```
public <T> List<T> findT(Class<T> clazz) {

    String constructorVariables = Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredFields())
            .map(Field::getName)
            .reduce((s1, s2) -> s1 + ", " + s2)
            .orElse("");

    var p = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT new " + clazz.getName() + "(" + constructorVariables + ") FROM Person p",
            clazz
    ).getResultList();
}
```

In this approach the projection-class needs to have the same field names as the database-table columns.